# Can you correct me the mistake

Tags: html, css

I am a very beginner to HTML and CSS. When I'm practicing CSS drop down menus, sub menus are inline and not aligned properly. Let me know the mistake what I have done and rectify the mistake.

```css
#menu{ list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
#menu li{ display:inline; }
#menu li a{ text-decoration:none; background-color:#FFAAFF; color:Black; display:inline-block; padding: 20px 40px; }
#menu li a:hover{ background-color:#AA7FFF; color:White; }

.submenu{ display:none;position:absolute; top:66px; margin:0; padding:0; }
.submenu li a{ display:inline-block; }
#menu li:hover .submenu{ display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Drop down menu</title>
    <link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
     <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1.4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2.4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3.4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
     </ul>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please can you make it clear what result you are expecting to see e.g. the position of the submenu, whether the the items should be horizontal or vertical etc...

Comment: Vertical. Should be displayed below the parent menu...

Answer (score 1):

HI now add this css Define your `.submenu` and `#menu li` this css

```
.submenu{    top: 100%;left: 0;}

#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

```css
#menu{ list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
#menu li{ display:inline; }
#menu li a{ text-decoration:none; background-color:#FFAAFF; color:Black; display:inline-block; padding: 20px 40px; }
#menu li a:hover{ background-color:#AA7FFF; color:White; }

.submenu{ display:none;position:absolute; top:66px; margin:0; padding:0; }
.submenu li a{ display:inline-block; }
#menu li:hover .submenu{ display:inline-block; }
.submenu{    top: 100%;left: 0;}

#menu li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Drop down menu</title>
    <link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
     <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1.4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2.4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3.4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
     </ul>     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## menu li {display: -webkit-inline-box; position: relative;}

use this css
And Must check display for all browser